# Create pointer on heap in custom constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

```
class Person {
  public:
    int *p_age;
    Person(int);
 };

Person::Person(int age) {
  p_age = new int(age);
}
```

I am getting more familiar with c++ memory management, but I'm not sure yet how to validate for myself what memory is created on the stack vs. heap. Here is an example: I believe I have created the pointer `p_age` on the heap in a custom constructor, but before I run into any issue later, is there some way I can validate this kind of thing at run-time for my own sanity?

Comment: If you `new` something, it is on the free store (heap).  Otherwise it is either static (allocated in the data block or the zero initialized block or the read-only-data block), or automatic (stack).

Comment: "_I am getting more familiar with c++ memory management_" - but why not do that after you've gotten familiar with what C++ has to offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ itself does not have any notion of stack or heap. These are implementation details of the C++ implementation, but usually they translate to what the standard calls *objects with automatic storage duration* and *objects with dynamic storage duration*.

In that sense, your `p_age` *points to* an `int` object with dynamic storage duration (i.e. on the heap) after the assignment from `new`. `p_age`'s (the pointer, not the object it points to) own storage duration is however dependent on how its parent object of type `Person`, of which it is a subobject, is created, e.g. with `Person person{42};` in a function body, `person` and `person.p_age` would have automatic storage duration (i.e. they are on the stack), while `*(person.p_age)`, the object that `person.p_age` points to, still has dynamic storage duration (i.e. lives on the heap).

There is no way to test whether an object pointed to by a pointer has dynamic or automatic storage duration at runtime. It is the programmer's job to ensure that these do not get mixed up and you e.g. accidentally call `delete` on a pointer to an object of automatic storage duration. This is why you should rarely use `new` (which always creates objects with dynamic storage duration) and instead encapsulate every object with dynamic storage duration by an object of automatic storage duration managing it, e.g. using `std::unique_ptr`, so that explicit calls to `delete` become unnecessary.

In particular in your example, there does not seem to be a reason for dynamic allocation (whether directly with `new` or through a `std::unique_ptr`) at all. The "age" should be part of a "Person", i.e. if a "Person" is created or destroyed, then so should its "age". Therefore `p_age` should have type `int`, not `int*` and should be simply assigned to in the constructor:

```
Person::Person(int age) : p_age(age) {
}
```

which is using the *member initializer list* syntax to directly initialize (rather than assign after initialization as in your code) `p_age` with `age`'s value.

Comment: Thanks @uneven_mark, I appreciate the delineation you made between the specification and the implementation, and your thorough and thoughtful comments.